# UIPinchGestureRecognizer (Zoom out /Zoom in)

Tags: ipad, uipinchgesturerecognizer

i have used UIPinchGestureRecognizer in my application for  zoom in or zoom out the image.its working  on zoom in /zoom out .
but i want to set the minimum and maximum scale of UIPinchGestureRecognizer So that the image is not zoom out smaller Than  the ipad size . there is any way to set scale minimum and maximum scale of UIPinchGestureRecognizer. 
please reply me as soon as.

Thanks
Pooja Rusia
 iphone Developer

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get pinch scale into pinchScale

float scale = fmaxf(pinchScale,
    fminf(ipadWidth / imageWidth, ipadHeight / imageHeight));

// Use scale instead of pinchScale
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think it is better to take imageview into scrollview, By default scrollview has Zooming in - Zooming out options with implementing its delegate methods....not a problem also take pinch gesture it is also good one , you can fallow fallowing links ,they are helpful i think so...

using pinch gesture recognizer you can use these links for your requirement...

[Limit maximum scale for scaling image with pinch gesture in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647084/limit-maximum-scale-for-scaling-image-with-pinch-gesture-in-ios)

http://paulsolt.com/2011/03/limiting-uipinchgesturerecognizer-zoom-levels/

[UIPinchGestureRecognizer for zooming and panning an image in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954582/uipinchgesturerecognizer-for-zooming-and-panning-an-image-in-xcode)

[Max/Min Scale of Pinch Zoom in UIPinchGestureRecognizer - iPhone iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios)

Thank you