# Max/Min Scale of Pinch Zoom in UIPinchGestureRecognizer - iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, cgaffinetransform

How would I be able to limit the scale of the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to a min and max level?  The scale property below seems to be relative to the last known scale (the delta from last state) and I can't figure out how to set a limit to the size/heigh of the object being zoomed.

```
-(void)scale:(id)sender {

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat pinchscale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform holderTransform = holderView.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
```

}

Comment: look this sample on pinch zoom http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-using-uipinchgesturerecogniz.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't a way to limit the scale on a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. To limit the height in your code, you should be able to do something like this:

```
CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);
CGRect bounds = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].bounds;
scale = MIN(scale, maximumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));
scale = MAX(scale, minimumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));
```

To limit width, change 'Height' to 'Width' in the last two lines.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you transform the view at all, the frame is invalid. For example, if the view is rotated at 45 degrees, the frame is actually much bigger than the actual uiview, so the scale factor will change as you rotate and then try to clamp it.

Comment: that works, or you can work with scale values instead of specific height/width values as in my answer.

Answer (score 110):

Here is the solution that I figured out after using Anomie's answer as a starting point.

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

        // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
        const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]); 
        newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);   
        newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call  
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution!  I have been looking for this forever!  Why is it not at the top of this question!?  Thanks

Comment: Add this line after setting gestureRecognizer view's transform: [recognizer setScale:1.0];

Comment: Hello i am using ionic latest framework 2.0.0 beta. i will opened image full size in ionic image model. but in latest version of ionic not support image scrolling. so please help me if you know.

Comment: var currentScale: CGFloat = CFloat(recognizer.view!.layer(valueForKeyPath: "transform.scale"))! Here I am getting Error of  >>>Cannot call value of non-function type 'CALayer'

Answer (score 4):

I took some info gleaned from Paul Solt and Anoime's answers, and added that to an existing category I have made for UIViewController to allow making any UIView draggable, to now make it pinchable using gestures and transforms.

Note: this dirties the tag property of the view you are making draggable/pinchable. So if you needed the tag for something else, you can consider placing that value in the NSMutableDictionary being used by this technique. That's available as **[self dictForView:theView]**

**Implementing in your project:**

You can make any subview within the view controllers "view" draggable or pinchable (or both)
place a single line of code in your viewDidLoad (for example:)

```
[self makeView:mySubView draggable:YES pinchable:YES minPinchScale:0.75 maxPinchScale:1.0];
```

turn it off in viewDidUnload (releases guestures & dictionary):

```
[self makeView:mySubView draggable:NO pinchable:NO minPinchScale:1.0 maxPinchScale:1.0];
```

**DragAndPinchScale.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (DragAndPinchScale)

-(void) makeView:(UIView*)aView 
       draggable:(BOOL)draggable 
       pinchable:(BOOL)pinchable 
   minPinchScale:(CGFloat)minPinchScale
   maxPinchScale:(CGFloat)maxPinchScale;


-(NSMutableDictionary *) dictForView:(UIView *)theView;
-(NSMutableDictionary *) dictForViewGuestures:(UIGestureRecognizer *)guesture;

@end
```

**DragAndPinchScale.m file**

```
#import "DragAndPinchScale.h"

@implementation UIViewController (DragAndPinchScale)


-(NSMutableDictionary *) dictForView:(UIView *)theView{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary*) (void*) theView.tag;
    if (!dict) {
        dict = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] retain];
        theView.tag = (NSInteger) (void *) dict;
    }

    return dict;

}


-(NSMutableDictionary *) dictForViewGuestures:(UIGestureRecognizer *)guesture {
    return [self dictForView:guesture.view];
}


- (IBAction)fingersDidPinchInPinchableView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)fingers {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self dictForViewGuestures:fingers];
    UIView *viewToZoom = fingers.view;
    CGFloat lastScale;
    if([fingers state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [fingers scale];
    } else {
        lastScale = [[dict objectForKey:@"lastScale"] floatValue];
    }

    if ([fingers state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [fingers state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat currentScale = [[[fingers view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

        // limits to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        CGFloat maxScale = [[dict objectForKey:@"maxScale"] floatValue];
        CGFloat minScale = [[dict objectForKey:@"minScale"] floatValue];

        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [fingers scale]); 
        newScale = MIN(newScale, maxScale / currentScale);   
        newScale = MAX(newScale, minScale / currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[fingers view] transform], newScale, newScale);
        viewToZoom.transform = transform;

        lastScale = [fingers scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call  
    }

    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:lastScale] 
             forKey:@"lastScale"];

}

- (void)fingerDidMoveInDraggableView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)finger {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self dictForViewGuestures:finger];
    UIView *viewToDrag =  finger.view;
    if (finger.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        [dict setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:viewToDrag.frame.origin] 
                 forKey:@"startDragOffset"];

        [dict setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[finger locationInView:self.view]] 
                 forKey:@"startDragLocation"];


    }
    else if (finger.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary*) (void*) viewToDrag.tag;

        CGPoint stopLocation = [finger locationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint startDragLocation = [[dict valueForKey:@"startDragLocation"] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint startDragOffset = [[dict valueForKey:@"startDragOffset"] CGPointValue];
        CGFloat dx = stopLocation.x - startDragLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = stopLocation.y - startDragLocation.y;
        //   CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
        CGRect dragFrame = viewToDrag.frame;


        CGSize selfViewSize = self.view.frame.size;
        if (!UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
            selfViewSize = CGSizeMake(selfViewSize.height,selfViewSize.width);
        }

        selfViewSize.width  -= dragFrame.size.width;
        selfViewSize.height -= dragFrame.size.height;

        dragFrame.origin.x = MIN(selfViewSize.width, MAX(0,startDragOffset.x+dx));
        dragFrame.origin.y = MIN(selfViewSize.height,MAX(0,startDragOffset.y+dy));

        viewToDrag.frame = dragFrame;
    }
    else if (finger.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"startDragLocation"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"startDragOffset"];
    }
}

-(void) makeView:(UIView*)aView 
       draggable:(BOOL)draggable 
       pinchable:(BOOL)pinchable 
   minPinchScale:(CGFloat)minPinchScale
   maxPinchScale:(CGFloat)maxPinchScale{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary*) (void*) aView.tag;

    if (!(pinchable || draggable)) {

        if (dict){ 
            [dict release];
            aView.tag = 0;
        }
        return;
    }

    if (dict) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan =[dict objectForKey:@"UIPanGestureRecognizer"];
        if(pan){
            if ([aView.gestureRecognizers indexOfObject:pan]!=NSNotFound) {
                [aView removeGestureRecognizer:pan];
            }
            [dict removeObjectForKey:@"UIPanGestureRecognizer"];
        }

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch =[dict objectForKey:@"UIPinchGestureRecognizer"];
        if(pinch){
            if ([aView.gestureRecognizers indexOfObject:pinch]!=NSNotFound) {
                [aView removeGestureRecognizer:pinch];
            }
            [dict removeObjectForKey:@"UIPinchGestureRecognizer"];
        }

        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"startDragLocation"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"startDragOffset"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"lastScale"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"minScale"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:@"maxScale"];
    }


    if (draggable) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fingerDidMoveInDraggableView:)];
        pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;  
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;  
        [aView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
        [pan release];

        dict = [self dictForViewGuestures:pan];
        [dict setObject:pan forKey:@"UIPanGestureRecognizer"];

    }

    if (pinchable) {


        CGAffineTransform initialTramsform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        aView.transform = initialTramsform;


        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fingersDidPinchInPinchableView:)];
        [aView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
        [pinch release];
        dict = [self dictForViewGuestures:pinch];
        [dict setObject:pinch forKey:@"UIPinchGestureRecognizer"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:minPinchScale] forKey:@"minScale"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:maxPinchScale] forKey:@"maxScale"];


    }

}

@end
```

Comment: thanks it worked fine with my code.
i was facing this issue for so long but your above code helped me to solve it.
thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The problem with most of the other answers is that they are trying to deal with scale as a linear value, when in fact it is non-linear due to the way `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` calculates its scale property based on the touch distance. When this isn't taken into account, the user must use more or less pinch distance to 'undo' the scaling applied by a previous pinch gesture.

Consider: suppose `transform.scale` = `1.0` and I place my fingers 6cm apart on the screen, then pinch inwards to 3cm apart - the resulting `gestureRecognizer.scale` is `0.5`, and `0.5-1.0` is `-0.5`, so `transform.scale` will become `1.0+(-0.5)` = `0.5`. Now, I lift my fingers, place them back down 3cm apart and pinch outwards to 6cm. The resulting `gestureRecognizer.scale` will be `2.0`, and `2.0-1.0` is `1.0`, so `transform.scale` will become `0.5+1.0` = `1.5`. Not what I wanted to happen.

The fix is to calculate the delta pinch scale as a proportion of its previous value. I place my fingers down 6cm apart, and pinch inwards to 3cm, so `gestureRecognizer.scale` is `0.5`. `0.5/1.0` is `0.5`, so my new `transform.scale` is `1.0*0.5` = `0.5`. Next, I place my fingers down 3cm apart, and pinch outwards to 6cm. `gestureRecognizer.scale` is then `2.0`, and `2.0/1.0` is `2.0`, so my new `transform.scale` is `0.5*2.0` = `1.0`, which is exactly what I wanted to happen.

Here it is in code:

in `-(void)viewDidLoad`:

```
self.zoomGestureCurrentZoom = 1.0f;
```

in `-(void)onZoomGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer`:

```
if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
{
    self.zoomGestureLastScale = gestureRecognizer.scale;
}
else if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged )
{
    // we have to jump through some hoops to clamp the scale in a way that makes the UX intuitive
    float scaleDeltaFactor = gestureRecognizer.scale/self.zoomGestureLastScale;
    float currentZoom = self.zoomGestureCurrentZoom;
    float newZoom = currentZoom * scaleDeltaFactor;
    // clamp
    float kMaxZoom = 4.0f;
    float kMinZoom = 0.5f;
    newZoom = MAX(kMinZoom,MIN(newZoom,kMaxZoom));    
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newZoom, newZoom);

    // store for next time
    self.zoomGestureCurrentZoom = newZoom;
    self.zoomGestureLastScale = gestureRecognizer.scale;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when I set it to a specific view, the gestureRecognizer.view

I have run into issues where the "speed" wasn't the same for multiple pinches, and I think that's what you're getting at.

Comment: @PaulSolt hmm, yeah.. I guess where I've got `[[gestureRecognizer view] transform]` that could perhaps by `CGAffineTransformIdentity`? I think in the code I based this on, `self.view` was supposed to be different to `gestureRecognizer.view`. Can't remember sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, really useful code snippet above clamping to a minimum and maximum scale.

I found that when I flipped the view first using:

```
CGAffineTransformScale(gestureRecognizer.view.transform, -1.0, 1.0);
```

it would cause a flicker when scaling the view.

Let me know what you think but the solution for me was to update the code sample above, and if the view has been flipped (flag set via property) then invert the scale value:

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer     state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    if(self.isFlipped) // (inverting)
    {
        currentScale *= -1;
    }

    CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (self.lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);

    newScale = MIN(newScale, self.maximumScaleFactor / currentScale);
    newScale = MAX(newScale, self.minimumScaleFactor / currentScale);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
    gestureRecognizer.view.transform = transform;

    self.lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
```

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1

`gestureRecognizer.scale` **start with 1.0 at the beginning of pinch (gestureRecognizer.state == .began)**, and `gestureRecognizer.scale` in later state (.changed or .end) is always based on that, for example, if the view size is `view_size` at the beginning of pinch (might not be the same with the original size `orig_view_size`), `gestureRecognizer.scale` always starts with 1.0, and if it becomes 2.0 later, it's size will be `2 * view_size`, so the scale always based on that when the pinch starts.

And we can get the scale **at the beginning of pinch (gestureRecognizer.state == .began)** `lastScale = self.imageView.frame.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width`, so the scale of the original image now should be `lastScale * gestureRecognizer.scale`

- `lastScale`: The scale of last round of Pinch, a round of Pinch is from state.start to state.end, and the scale is based on the original view size.
- `gestureRecognizer.scale`: current scale, based on the view size after last round of Pinch.
- `currentScale`: current scale, based on the orignial view size.
- `newScale`: new scale, based on the **orignial view size**. `newScale = lastScale * gestureRecognizer.scale`, and you can limit the scale of the view by comparing the limitation with `newScale`.

```

```
var lastScale:CGFloat = 1.0

@objc func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        var newScale = gestureRecognizer.scale
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            lastScale = self.imageView.frame.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width
        }
        newScale = newScale * lastScale

        if newScale < minScale {
            newScale = minScale
        } else if newScale > maxScale {
            newScale = maxScale
        }

        let currentScale = self.imageView.frame.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)
        print("last Scale: \(lastScale), current scale: \(currentScale), new scale: \(newScale), gestureRecognizer.scale: \(gestureRecognizer.scale)")
}
```

```

## Method 2

`gestureRecognizer.scale` **start with 1.0 on each Pinch notification**, this require you reset `gestureRecognizer.scale = 1` in the code in the end of each notification handler, so now `gestureRecognizer.scale` is based on the view size of last Pinch notification, **NOT based on the view size at the beginning of pinch**. This is the most important difference with method 1. And since we don't rely on the scale of last round, we don't need `lastScale` anymore.

- `currentScale`: current scale, based on the orignial view size.
- `gestureRecognizer.scale`: new scale, based on the **view size of last Pinch (not the last round)**, the scale value based on the orignial view size will be `currentScale * gestureRecognizer.scale`

And we use `transform.scaledBy` now, which use the scale based on **view size of last Pinch (not the last round)**.

```

```
@objc func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentScale = self.imageView.frame.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width
        var newScale = gestureRecognizer.scale
        if currentScale * gestureRecognizer.scale < minScale {
            newScale = minScale / currentScale
        } else if currentScale * gestureRecognizer.scale > maxScale {
            newScale = maxScale / currentScale
        }
        self.imageView.transform = self.imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: newScale, y: newScale)

        print("current scale: \(currentScale), new scale: \(newScale)")

        gestureRecognizer.scale = 1
}
```

```

Comment: Only your code is Swift. So, what is the initial values of maxScale and minScale?

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci, I set minScale to 1 and maxScale to 5

Answer (score 1):

Other approaches mentioned here did not work for me, but taking a couple things from previous answers and (in my opinion) simplifying things, I've got this to work for me. `effectiveScale` is an ivar set to 1.0 in `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)zoomScale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Reset last scale
        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
    [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat pinchscale = [recognizer scale];
        CGFloat scaleDiff = pinchscale - lastScale;

        if (scaleDiff < 0)
            scaleDiff *= 2; // speed up zoom-out
        else
            scaleDiff *= 0.7; // slow down zoom-in

        effectiveScale += scaleDiff;
        // Limit scale between 1 and 2
        effectiveScale = effectiveScale < 1 ? 1 : effectiveScale;
        effectiveScale = effectiveScale > 2 ? 2 : effectiveScale;

        // Handle transform in separate method using new effectiveScale    
        [self makeAndApplyAffineTransform];
        lastScale = pinchscale;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a somewhat complicated way of handling the non-linearity inherent in the gesture recognizer's `scale` property, and also it doesn't actualy properly handle it, it just does a scale by 0.7. See my answer for a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    //recognizer.scale=1;

    CGFloat pinchScale = recognizer.scale;
    pinchScale = round(pinchScale * 1000) / 1000.0;
    NSLog(@"%lf",pinchScale);

if (pinchScale < 1)

 {

 currentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentLabel.font.fontName size:

(currentLabel.font.pointSize - pinchScale)];

   recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);

 [currentLabel sizeToFit];

  recognizer.scale=1;
    }
  else
    {
        currentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentLabel.font.fontName size:(currentLabel.font.pointSize + pinchScale)];

         recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);

         [currentLabel sizeToFit];

        recognizer.scale=1;
    }
    //currentLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

   // [currentLabel sizeToFit];
    NSLog(@"Font :%@",label.font);
}
```

Comment: ohhhh thats very nice its really work thx...!!
BUT i want to change my lable frame in this method i try it but it is not work perfectly horizontally and vertically on pinch it change its hight and width so can you help me for that... THX...Mr Arvind Kumar.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pinchToZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    switch (gesture.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            lastScale = gesture.scale;
        }break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {   
            const CGFloat zoomSensitivity = 5;
            const CGFloat zoomMin = 1;
            const CGFloat zoomMax = 16;

            CGFloat objectScale = gesture.view.contentScaleFactor;
            CGFloat zoomDiff = lastScale - gesture.scale;
            CGFloat zoomDirty = objectScale - zoomDiff * zoomSensivity;
            CGFloat zoomTo = fmaxf(zoomMin, fminf(zoomDirty, zoomMax));

            // step round if needed (neutralize elusive changes)
            zoomTo = (NSInteger)(zoomTo * 10) * 0.1;

            if ( objectScale != zoomTo )
                gesture.view.contentScaleFactor = zoomTo;

            lastScale = gesture.scale;
        }break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @Paul Solt solution - that is great btw, and adapted it to Swift, for those interested

```
@objc func pinchUpdated(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
            lastScale = recognizer.scale
        }

        if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {

            let currentScale = recognizer.view!.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as! CGFloat

            // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
            let maxScale: CGFloat = 4.0
            let ninScale: CGFloat = 0.9

            var newScale: CGFloat = 1 -  (lastScale - recognizer.scale)
            newScale = min(newScale, maxScale / currentScale)
            newScale = max(newScale, ninScale / currentScale)
            recognizer.view!.transform = recognizer.view!.transform.scaledBy(x: newScale, y: newScale)

            lastScale = recognizer.scale // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use a scroll view instead? Then you could use scrollView.minimumZoomScale and scrollView.maximumZoomScale

Comment: hmmm, interesting...will look into that as an alternative approach to the problem.