# How to reload view while user pinching UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

I have view with CGPathRef and when user zooming this view by pinching view dont't reload:
[image]
But after zooming view reload:
[image]

However I need to reload view while user pinching it.
How can I do it? Or is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for current pinching using the UIPinchGestureRecognizerStateChanged. 
This has an example of how it is implemented: [Max/Min Scale of Pinch Zoom in UIPinchGestureRecognizer - iPhone iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios)

Comment: Thank you, but I solute this problem by scrollview delegate method - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView, in which I set scrollview content scale factor.