# How to reduce velocity of pinch-zoom UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I've created a `UIGestureRecognizer` much like <kbd>[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios)</kbd>:

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

        // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
        const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]); 
        newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);   
        newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call  
    }
}
```

This works as expected, however my client wants it to be *less* sensitive to touch. How can I reduce the velocity of the pinching (both inward and outward) so that it zooms at about 80% the default velocity?

Comment: Did you try to set manually the `zoomScale` of your `scrollView` ?

Comment: @NicolasBonnet unfortunately this particular one isn't wrapped in a scroll view, so it's not feasible to do that :|

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to `scale` the current value to the 80%.

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat maxScale = 2.0;
    CGFloat currentScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    currentScale = 0.8 * currentScale;   //80% of scaling

    if(currentScale < 0.8)
        currentScale = 0.8;

    if(currentScale > maxScale)
        currentScale = maxScale;

    [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], currentScale, currentScale);

}
```

Comment: I believe this will work too but why cropping your scale value, i don't think there is a need for that.

Comment: Cropping the Scale value because it can limit your scaling property.

Comment: ok sorry i see i have read to quickly the original code and missed that part.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work at all - has some really bizarre opposite effects :|

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- (void)handlePinching:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (CGRectIsEmpty(self.initalFrame)) {
            self.initalFrame = gestureRecognizer.view.frame;
            // store view's original frame and never change it
        }

        if (self.preScale == 0.f) {
            self.preScale = 1.f; 
        }

        gestureRecognizer.scale = self.preScale;
        // gestureRecognizer and view should share the same scale state at the beginning
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
        const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

        CGFloat newScale = gestureRecognizer.scale;

        newScale = (newScale - self.preScale) * 0.8 + self.preScale;

        newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale);
        newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale);


        CGRect newFrame = self.initalFrame;
        newFrame.size.height *= newScale;
        newFrame.size.width *= newScale;
        gestureRecognizer.view.frame = newFrame;
        self.preScale = newScale;
    }

}
```

The points are

- use frame to implement scale.
- do change to the scale variable's change  to slow/speed scaling.

Comment: Tried messing around quite a bit with this but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the excessive speed of the zoom was actually a bug in the linked answer's code. Sadly this doesn't actually answer my actual question though (for which I'd still like an answer!), but it does serve to solve my client's problem.

Note the added line at the bottom that resets the gestureRecognizer back to 1:

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

        ...

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call  

        gestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
        // ^ added this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, Not added that line in my code, my mistake.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi hrm. Now you got me thinking - maybe your suggestion *will* work after all with that line in there. Going to try it out.