# scaling of a view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransformscale

I have three UIViews (A, B, C) where A contains B and C.  I want to be able to scale view B, by detecting a Pinch gesture with a UIPinchGestureRecognizer and then using CGAffineTransformScale to scale view B.

However, when I scale B it scales OK, but expands outside its original area of the screen - I'd like to keep the area of the screen which contains B the same and just show a smaller piece of it, but magnified.

Is there something I can set to keep the view's area the same?

Comment: Could be that your view A is set to not clip subviews. Without more details we can't be sure.

Comment: how would i set this? is it a property on view A?

Comment: Yes, it's a property. It prevents any of its subviews from drawing outside of its bounds. If you are sure that A isn't changing its size then this is likely the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
viewA.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

With clipsToBounds set to YES, you will see the part of the viewB and viewC that fits within the bounds of the viewA. Otherwise, if clipsToBounds is set to NO, you will see the entire viewB and viewC, even the parts are outside the viewA

Comment: To "initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame" for view A, I added:
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

However, when I expand view B, it covers the area of view C.

When I'm creating view B, I set the bounds as follows:
    [self setBounds:CGRectMake(ROOTX, ROOTY, GRIDX, GRIDY )];
(which maps to 0,0,400,400)

Comment: Sorry - editing problems in my previous answer:

To "initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame" for view A, I added: [self setClipsToBounds:YES]; However, when I expand view B, it covers the area of view C. When I'm creating view B, I set the bounds as follows: [self setBounds:CGRectMake(ROOTX, ROOTY, GRIDX, GRIDY )]; (which maps to 0,0,400,400)

Comment: so you want viewB and viewC not to collide with each other ?

Comment: Yes - if I can stop this.

Comment: then you have to add condition when you are handling gesturerecognizer

Comment: At the start, the two views are next to another, so any scaling will move into the other view.  
Going back a step, I'm trying to "magnify" the data in view, so instead of showing a 400 square units of data in a 400 unit square, I want to show 200 square units twice as big in the 400 unit square area. Am I using the wrong approach?    

At the moment the I have:  
 -(void)zoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  
{   
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);  
    recognizer.scale = 1;  
}

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154514/2553526 to limit your transformation..