# Expand and compress the circle on pinch in and pinch out in ios

Tags: ios

I have code to draw a circle in ios

```
int size = 60
int radius = size/2;

self.tapSelectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(longPressedPoint.x - radius, longPressedPoint.y - radius, size, size)];
self.tapSelectionView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
self.tapSelectionView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.tapSelectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tapSelectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
[self.view addSubview:self.tapSelectionView];

CGPoint centerOfOriginalFrame = CGPointMake(self.tapSelectionView.frame.origin.x + radius, self.tapSelectionView.frame.origin.y + radius);
centerOfDrawnCircle = centerOfOriginalFrame;
```

and now I want to make this circle to expand and compress on pinch in and pinch out gestures in ios.Could anyone please help me on how to get this, i'm new to ios development.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add pinch gesture to your circle i.e on `tapSelectionView`
2. on pinch gesture action:- set  `CGAfflineTransform` to your `tapSelectionView` i.e transform scale to expand(zoom out) and (zoom in)

If you need example code you can surely see this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios)