# How to get pinch effect to an image in iphone

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.

I want to get the pinch effect to an image means i want to change the shape of an image when i perform pinching on an image. I don't know is it possible or not, if it is possible can any one help me to do it using objective c in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your question itself is a big concept..Atleast you must have tried something to achieve it..we can help you out with the modules..

for a jump start -

study about `touchesBegan:,touchesMoved:,and touchesEnded` methods.

Instead of using Gesture Recogniser, try to make your own pinch effect by the above methods..

U'll get much more flexibility to control the touch points.

Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to associate a pinch gesture (type of **UIPinchGestureRecognizer**)with your `UIImageView` .

Check the below blog tutorial with sample code

[Working with UIGesturerecognizer](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/)

[Sample code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Sorry if u r not clear with my question.I want a pinch effect to an image not to an image view like http://www.abcpdf.com/helpie/source/2-effects/pinch.htm, means not resizing of a view with pinch gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You can find help here : [Limit maximum scale for scaling image with pinch gesture in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647084/image-maximum-scale-by-pinch-gesture-in-ios)

Basically, using a gesture, you get a factor that you use to scale your image.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Sorry if u r not clear with my question.I want a pinch effect to an image not to an image view like http://www.abcpdf.com/helpie/source/2-effects/pinch.htm, means not resizing of a view with pinch gesture.