# Setting UIScrollView's origin for pinch gestures

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm creating a scroll view for displaying a very large view, and I need both scroll and zoom functionality (just like an image viewer). Here are the steps that I've taken:

1. In interface builder, I've put a scroll viewer to the view controller.
2. I've added a pinch gesture recognizer to the scroll viewer.
3. I've connected the gesture recognizer's action to the code to handle the gesture events.
4. When the view controller is loaded, I change my view's origin to the center (`viewer` is my scroll viewer): `self.viewer.contentOffset = CGPointMake(384, 512);`
5. In my code for the handler, I handled the event as such:

(`startScale` is 1.0 in the beginning)

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        startScale *= sender.scale;
    }else{
        float result = sender.scale * startScale;

        self.viewer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(result, result);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the gesture is recognized and scaling works correctly, however, the whole view scales with respect to the `0,0` point of the screen (top left). I want it to scale with respect to the middle point that I'm applying the gesture, just as a natural pinch gesture for zooming into a photo.

I've also tried setting `self.viewer.frame`'s origin, but nothing changed. I've searched about the problem and found these:

[How to set a UIView's origin reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012406/how-to-set-a-uiviews-origin-reference) (already tried)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163279/pinch-punch-gestures-center (about my problem, but unanswered)

[UIPinchGestureRecognizer for zooming and panning an image in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954582/uipinchgesturerecognizer-for-zooming-and-panning-an-image-in-xcode) (looks like an overkill, too complicated for me, and I'm not sure if this would really help my situation)

How can I achieve natural pinching with my scroll view, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer to the problem is very simple: Remove the pinch gesture altogether. The benefit of using a UIScrollView is that it handles the panning/zooming internally, and you have to do nothing

Edit: To make sure the content is scaled properly, you are going to need a `UIView` (called `contentView` or whatever you want) where you put all the content, and then on the delegate method of your `UIScrollView` do this:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return contentView;
}
```

This should solve your problem

Edit 2: Also remember to set the minimum / maximum zoom scales for your `UIScrollView`

Comment: oh, I didn't know it handled pinch internally. but unfortunalelly it didn't work. i removed the gesture recognizer, put all my content view in it, and tried this:

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.innerView;
}

but now nothing happens when i pinch?

Comment: one observation: viewForZoomingInScrollView is never called. (yes, i've connected my view controller as scroll view's delegate)

Comment: ok, solved the problem: i needed to set minimum/maximum zoom scales of the scroll view. could you please add those requirements too to the answer for the future visitors?